# Identifying related USB devices

Tags: c#, usb, zebra-printers, smartcard-reader

Is there a way using C# to identifying a device and associated child USB device(s)? For example I have a USB Zebra printer with a card reader mounted on it, and wish to know the card reader's name and identifying details i.e. build up a tree of associated devices.

```
USB Zebra Printer
---> USB Card Reader Name
```

Using a Powershell script I can see the devices I'm interested in;

```
gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} |
Sort Manufacturer,Description,DeviceID |
Ft -GroupBy Manufacturer Description,Service,DeviceID
```

Here's the output;

[image: Powershell Output]

Windows shows this information in the printer properties;

[image: Windows USB device tree]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Smartcard reader naming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612817/smartcard-reader-naming)

Comment: This might also be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940824/getting-pcsc-reader-serial-number-with-winscard

Answer (score 0):

This could be useful, just do the same as this guy and seperate the devices by comparing them to strings/eachother: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3331509/4424210